# how to communicate with c server from c# client using udp?

Tags: c#, c, sockets, udp, client-server

My problem description is as follows:

My `C#` client sends a udp packet using `sendto`. Because this is `C#`, this is a byte array that I have constructed.

The `C` server receives the packet using `recvfrom`. Through wireshark, I have confirmed that the `C#` program is sending the packet, and that the `C` program is receiving it. The `recvfrom` is not throwing any kind of error. But I am unable to extract any data out of the received packet. I receive it in a char array.

Specific details:
The `UDP` packet that i send is a request. Both the `c` program and the `C#` program are aware of the structure of the request. But since i am sending an array of bytes over the wire, this structure is irrelevant (i think).

Code:
`C#`:
Constructing the packet:
``

```
            byte[] tmpB;
            int j = 0;
            char[] reqStr = rsField.reqStr;

            for (; j < reqStr.Length; j++)
            {                    
                tmpB = BitConverter.GetBytes((char)reqStr[j]);
                for (int ctr = 0; ctr < tmpB.Length; ctr++)
                    retVal[i++] = tmpB[ctr];

            }//end of for

            tmpB = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)rsField.fieldLength);
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < tmpB.Length; ctr++)
                retVal[i++] = tmpB[ctr];

            tmpB = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)rsField.fieldType);
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < tmpB.Length; ctr++)
                retVal[i++] = tmpB[ctr];

            //------------------------------------------------------------


            tmpB = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)ctField.camType);
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < tmpB.Length; ctr++)
                retVal[i++] = tmpB[ctr];

            tmpB = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)ctField.fieldLength);
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < tmpB.Length; ctr++)
                retVal[i++] = tmpB[ctr];

            tmpB = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32)ctField.fieldType);
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < tmpB.Length; ctr++)
                retVal[i++] = tmpB[ctr];
```

...
``
As you can see, i have a mix of string and number fields. (These are not the only fields i have, code is shorted for readability)

`C`:
``

```
            char buf[1000];
    memset(&buf,'\0',sizeof(buf));
    length = recvfrom (i, &buf, sizeof(buf), 0,
               (struct sockaddr *)&remoteAddr, &fromLen);


    now = time(0);
    if (length == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s: recvfrom error - %m\n", ctime(&now));
        continue;
    }
    unsigned long fieldType1 = strtoul(bufPtr,0,10);
    bufPtr += 4 * sizeof(char);
    unsigned long fieldLength1 = strtoul(bufPtr,0,10);
    bufPtr += 4 * sizeof(char);
    unsigned long res = strtoul(bufPtr,0,10);

    printf("fieldType: %ld \t fieldLength: %ld \t res: %ld \t \n",fieldType1,fieldLength1,res);
```

...
``
I am convinced that I am missing a fundamental aspect in this whole thing. Please help me find out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Once the bits have been written to the wire, it isn't C, C++, C#, Java, FORTRAN, COBOL, lisp, scheme, scala, or anything else.  It's bits on a wire.  That's the fundamental aspect you are missing.  There's no structure to the data on the wire.

Once you read the data, it is up to you to take this collection of bytes and apply a structure to it.  That means you'll need to know that the first four bytes represent a number, and the lower order byte is stored at offest 0 from the beginning of the payload, the next higher byte is at offset 1, the next higher byte is at offset 2 and the highest order byte is at offset 3.  Your specific example might have nothing in common with the description above, but the idea of how to pack into bytes and unpack out of bytes is what you need to pay careful attention to.

Verify that at the lowest level you are writing all bytes.  Keep a map of which data is in which bytes, and then write each side of the communication independently from the specification you just wrote.  Don't get tempted to write whole integers / shorts / data structures to the packet without converting them to bytes; otherwise, you'll find that the machines on both ends might have different opinions on how integers / shorts / data structures are represented.

Comment: Hi, What you say makes complete sense. But I have verified that what i want to send is being sent, and it is being received exactly as it is being sent. This is because i write to the buffer byte-by-byte. My original question remains, though. How do i receive it at the server end? Is there something wrong in receiving it in a char array? As stated earlier, wireshark confirms that the packet is being sent correctly.

Comment: In the server end, you should accept a byte array.  Depending on the language a char array might be the same thing (like in C) but in other languages chars are multi-byte.  If you are receiving in a muti-byte char environment, you'll find that the bytes are packed in without your explicit control (hence the ability to get it wrong).  Make sure you treat the payload as a byte array, and then write your mapping from bytes to other items explicitly.